# Htaccess caching system in subfolder not working

Tags: .htaccess, caching

Sorry if this is a duplicate: I found many questions about caching system, but my problem seems to tied to the fact that the whole script is working within a subfolder.

All I need to do is implementing a simple caching system for my website, but I can't get this to work.

Here's my `.htaccess` file (widely commented to be clear - sorry if too many comments are confusing):

```
RewriteEngine on
# Map for lower-case conversion of some case-insensitive arguments:
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
# The script lives into this subfolder:
RewriteBase /mydir/

# IMAGES
#     Checks if cached version exists...
RewriteCond cache/$1-$2-$3-{lc:$4}.$5 -f
#     ...if yes, redirects to cached version...
RewriteRule ^(hello|world)\/image\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_\s]+)\.(png|gif|jpeg?|jpg)$ cache/$1-$2-$3-{lc:$4}.$5 [L]
#     ...if no, tries to generate content dynamically.
RewriteRule ^(hello|world)\/image\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_\s]+)\.(png|gif|jpeg?|jpg)$ index.php?look=$1&action=image&size=$2&data=$3&name=$4&format=$5 [L,QSA]

# OTHER
#     This is always non-cached.
RewriteRule ^(hello|world)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_\s]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_\s]+)?\/?$ index.php?look=$1&action=$2&name=$3 [QSA]
```

Now, the issue is that the `RewriteCond` seems to be always failing, as the served image is always generated by PHP. I also tried prepending a `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`, but is still not working. If I move the whole script to the root directory, it magically starts working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing that you are doing wrong is trying to use a rewrite map in an `.htaccess` file. in  the first place.  According to the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html):

> The `RewriteMap` directive may not be used in `<Directory>` sections or `.htaccess` files. You must declare the map in server or virtualhost context. You may use the map, once created, in your `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives in those scopes. You just can't **declare** it in those scopes.

If your ISP / sysadmin has already defined the lc map then you can use it.  If not then you can only do case-sensitive file caching on Linux, because its FS naming is case sensitive.   However, since these are internally generated images, just drop the case conversion and stick to lower case.

%{DOCUMENT_ROOT} may not be set correctly at time of mod_rewrite execution on some shared hosting configurations. See my [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) for more hints.  Also here is the equivalent lines from my blog's `.htaccess` FYI.  The DR variable does work here, but didn't for my previous ISP, to I had to hard-code the parth

```
# For HTML cacheable blog URIs (a GET to a specific list, with no query params, 
# guest user and the HTML cache file exists) then use it instead of executing PHP

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !blog_user
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}%{QUERY_STRING}  =GET                    [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}html_cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(article-\d+|index|sitemap.xml|search-\w+|rss-[0-9a-z]*)$ \
                   html_cache/$1.html                                 [L,E=END:1]
```

Note that I bypass the cache if the user is logged on or for posts and if any query parameters are set.

### Footnote

Your match patterns are complicated because you are not using the syntax of regexps:  use the `\w` and you don't need to escape `.` in `[ ]` or `/` . Also the jpeg isn't right is it?  So why not:

```
RewriteRule ^(hello|world)/image/([.\w\-]+)/([.\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+\.(png|gif|jpe?g))$  \
              cache/$1-$2-$3-$4       [L]
```

etc.. Or even (given that the file rule will only match for valid files in the cache)

```
RewriteRule ^(hello|world)/image/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.*?\.(png|gif|jpe?g))$  \
              cache/$1-$2-$3-$4       [L]
```

The non-greedy modifier means that `(.+?)` is the same as `([^/]+)` so doing hacks like `../../../../etc/passwd` won't walk the file hierarchy.